# How to set a TextView to display text in one line in Android

Tags: android, textview

I've set a TextView as the display. I want to display the operation being performed in one line, for example:

```
9856243187 + 2457896123 - 214583
```

The problem is, when the input reaches the edge of the TextView - it jumps to the next line.

So, is there anyway to avoid this behavior and keep the input in one line, even if it goes out of the screen?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You should use `android:maxLines="1"` in your TextView tag. 
`android:singleLine="true"` is **deprecated**.

Comment: can't find a notice to depreciation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:singleLine

Answer (score 21):

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

is the answer

**Update :**

`android:singleLine` attribute has been deprecated since API Level 3, you can use

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated

Comment: can't find a notice to depreciation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:singleLine

Answer (score 14):

## **tl;dr**:

For new users seeing this question, use `android:singleLine="true"`. Ignore deprecation warnings.

### Explanation

According to [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36950033), setting `android:maxLines="1"` may cause your application to crash when some specific values are set in `android:ellipsize` as well. Apparently it affects most Android devices running 4.1 Jellybean through 6.0.1 Marshmallow (being fixed in 7.0 Nougat). Depending on your device, your mileage may vary. However, if you as a developer are targeting a wide range of devices, it is best to use `android:singleLine="true"` in order to prevent crashes.

Comment: Is this still an issue now?

Comment: As long as you target a minimum SDK lower than 24, this will always be an issue. And according to the [Android Version Distribution chart for February 5, 2018](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), 70.4% of devices using Google Play have not been updated to Nougat (SDK24), so raising the minimum SDK not might be a viable option for many.

Answer (score 5):

add the code in your Textview

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks guys single line did the tricks but i also had to remove the ellipsis:

```
android:ellipsize="none"
```

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: how is this different from the older answer by @Ravi

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually scroll your single line content then you should use TextView inside HorizontalScrollView

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Single line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the TextView to singeline.

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this one ?

```
<TextView
        android:text="Single line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Hope this will help you.