# Recyclerview items not showing with the same height

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

[This is my app where is the problem exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urwCV.png)

[I want my items to fit like this app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7xfj.png)

I'm using a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. My problem as you see in the image that the grid items aren't the same height when one of the items has a longer text. I'm loading the data from firebase and the notify the `Adapter` when the list has the data. I tried everything but can't find a solution to auto fit the items like the second image attached. Any help, please?

Here is my recyclerview item layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    >



    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartoonImg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:imgUrl="@{cartoon.thumb}"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tool:text="Cartoon Name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@{cartoon.title}" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverFlow. Please provide the layout of `recyclerview` item.xml

Comment: you need to change the `height of the item wrap_content to 100sp or what ever you liked`

Comment: I added my recyclerview item layout ankuranurag2

Comment: Vishal Yadav

I want an auto fit way not a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

**This will result into exactly what you need**

> Try replacing your `TextView` with this:

```
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tool:text="Cartoon Name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@{cartoon.title}" />
```

Comment: It will show always that space even if there is no title that needs these 2 lines, I guess he wants to be dynamic, if only one item is two lines make all 2 lines otherwise make it 1 line and normal height

Answer (score -1):

you can give a static height to your textview, this way it will be the same for all. But you may lose your text in this.

Comment: I know that. That's why I need an auto fit way not a fixed height.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the line

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

on your `CardView`, and since the descendants have `match_parent`, the size changes for your `TextView`.

To solve this, you can use the following property `android:maxLines="1"` inside your `TextView`. This will stop the TextView from jumping to the next line, but will crop the text.

Alternatively, you can use a static height instead of `match_parent` or `wrap_content`, that is, using a value. I strongly recommend using `48dp` since that is what [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/image-lists.html#specs) recommend.
Source:

- [How to set a TextView to display text in one line in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40563511/6818446)

Answer (score -2):

You can add to your TextView:

`android:ellipsize="start"`
`android:maxLines="1`

From API 26, you can use Autosizing TextView - check the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview