# Why does the MaterialButton display text in two lines instead of one?

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, materialbutton

I'm using `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` as a button :

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/openGallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/open_gallery"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_pink"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:backgroundTint="@null"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_gallery"
            app:iconSize="64sp"
            app:iconTint="@color/dark_pink"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/CutTopLeftBottomRight"
            app:strokeColor="@color/dark_pink"
            app:strokeWidth="6dp" />
```

As you can see, **OPEN GALLERY** is breaking into two lines instead of staying on a single line. The `MaterialButton's` width is set to fit the text content, but it doesn't seem to be considering this.

[image]

How to fix this issue without using `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

What I want :

[image]

Comment: "MaterialButton's width is set to fill the entire screen" - where?

Comment: @TheLibrarian Thank you for your comment. My apologies for writing it incorrectly. What I meant was that I set `wrap_content`, which means the width will take its content's width.

Comment: Have you tried "android:maxLines="1"?

Comment: Yes, `android:maxLines="1"` is cutting the word gallery

Comment: So wouldn't that mean that there is not enough space there for it? Also from UX standpoint - I think the word "Open" is sort of redundant, "Galery" in clickable widget already tells you what is going to happen when you click on it.

Comment: I don't have only that button; I have others. There's ample space for the button width to stretch. But still it's break the text and takes small width

Comment: fun side note about `maxLines`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377396/413127 (`maxLines` is the answer btw). If the text is then cut, thats a different layout problem now that this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is overflowing to the next line because you just don't have enough space. So the only option it got is either overflow to the next line or get truncated when maxLines is set to 1. It would be helpful if you could also paste the parent of this material button to give more insights.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, as I mentioned in the question, the button has a lot of space like the more than half of screen width are still free to use, and still it's break the text

Comment: Could you please add the Parent to this view?  
I know it's too long and you would have probably already resolved the issue. It would be intresting to know. 
I can see this view in one line if I set the text size a bit small. 32 is too big to fit in.